# How to force an invariant method throw a particular exception in C# Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, exception, code-contracts, throw, invariants

I want my object invariant method to throw a specific exception. Does it make sense? Is it possible in C#?

For instance, I have the following code, including class A with invariant method and exception class E. For now class E is not participating in A...

```
class A {
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void YisGreaterThanX() {
        Contract.Invariant(x < y);
    }
}

class E : Exception {
}
```

And what I need is the following. Like Contract.Requires it would be useful to have Contract.Invariant (or may be an attribute constructor, which accepts Exception-derived class).

```
class A {
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void YisGreaterThanX() {
        Contract.Invariant<E>(x < y);
    }
}

class E : Exception {
}
```

Is it a good intention? May be my logic is wrong?

Comment: `Contract.Requires` can throw exceptions to indicate bugs in the caller code. If `Contract.Invariant` throws, that pretty much always indicates a bug in your code. Can you expand on why you want to do this?

Comment: @hvd, thank for reply. Does it mean that one should include `Contract.Requires<E>(x < y)` in every constructor of type `public A(int x, int y)` and every similar methods? Or does it mean that the logic of class A is corrupted?..

Comment: Yes, in that case, I would definitely put that in the constructor. It's a combination of invalid arguments that's best indicated by an `ArgumentException`, rather than an instance of a class that then becomes unusable.

Comment: Putting it as a requirement on the constructor also helps with documentation: the code that calls the constructor knows that `x < y` is a requirement of that constructor. (For some reason, SO wouldn't let me edit my previous comment to include this even though less than five minutes had passed.)

Comment: Very helpful comments. But your suggestion entails code duplication (similar `Contract.Requires` in all similar methods), doesn't it? Should I write something like `Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Requirement(x, y));`, where `Requirement` is defined in the class A like `public Func<int, int, bool> Requirement { get { return (x, y) => x < y; } }`?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The static analyser will not understand that, not will it help in documentation. Yes, there may be a little duplication, but that's because two separate concepts are closely linked. The invariant is a promise by the class to its users. The requirements are restrictions by the class on its users. Those restrictions may be needed to maintain the invariant (`x < y` in your case, where both `x` and `y` are modifiable), but there can also be restrictions without any invariants, or there can be invariants that do not rely on any restrictions beyond what C# itself provides.

Comment: In most cases I have seen, the invariants are sufficiently different from yours that the duplication would never be a problem. If you do have large numbers of modifiable properties that may break invariants, I can understand that you'd spend a lot of time just copying and pasting. In that case, though, I worry that you may have overly complicated classes. Do you have a concrete example where the duplication would (in your opinion) be so large that it hinders maintenance of your code?

Comment: Indeed I had an example. But after your advice I can agree that this is a pure example of overcomplicated logic. Thus it seems to me, that I understand your reasoning. Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we aren't supposed to be [catching Contract failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639960/how-come-you-cannot-catch-code-contract-exceptions), and since there isn't an [overload for Contract.Invariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.invariant(v=vs.110).aspx) with an explicit specified exception, this answer is hopefully hypothetical.

So after all the disclaimers, you could hack something along the following lines, by wiring up a [ContractFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.contractfailed(v=vs.100).aspx) event handler:

```
Contract.ContractFailed += Contract_ContractFailed();
```

And in the handler, filter for `Invariant` failures, and handle the failure and re-throw your exception:

```
public static void Contract_ContractFailed(object sender,  ContractFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.FailureKind == ContractFailureKind.Invariant)
    {
        e.SetHandled();
        throw new E(e.Message, e.OriginalException);
    }
}
```

Given that you can't pass much information in the `Contract.Invariant` definition, if you needed to parameterize the thrown exception, you would need to encode the intended exception into e.g. the [`bool, string` `Contract.Invariant` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412886(v=vs.110).aspx), or use external global state, such as thread local storage.

All of these are smelly IMO. So to answer your last question, I believe throwing catchable exceptions isn't a good idea at all - your code is being called out of its designed range of state, so there is a bug / validation missing somewhere.

**Edit**
Noticed subsequently that handling + throwing in the `ContractFailed` handler is still wrapped in the internal `ContractException`. So you'll need to unpack, e.g.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   var myException = ex.InnerException;
   // ... do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. E.g., if one were using your suggested "smelly" technique, he couldn't catch an exception in the catch-block of the code `try { var a = new A(0, 0); } catch (Exception e) { var x = e.Message; }`?

Comment: By handling `ContractFailed`, setting `SetHandled` and then re-raising another exception, in effect it allows you to `convert` the Failure to a defined and catchable exception, so yes, you can then put a `try` / `catch` around this. This is smelly in that it defeats the purpose of `ContractException` as being 'fatal' and uncatchable.

Comment: But the code `try { var a = new A(0, 0); } catch (Exception e) { var x = e.Message; }` does NOT catch an exception. A debugger stops at the last brace of the method `public static void Contract_ContractFailed(object sender,  ContractFailedEventArgs e)` in your answer and shows a notice about unhandled exception E. What am I missing?

Comment: It might just be your debugging settings in VS? i.e. it is breaking on all Ex's, not just unhandled?

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong with my recent comment. This code works as it is expected, and the debugger settings are correct. Somehow I thought that a debugger shouldn't run the Exception Assistant in the case of exceptions which will be handle further. Your assumption has helped me to understand this. Thanks a lot for the answer.